Terraform Error while Subnet Creation in Azure
I am trying to create 3 subnets from a VNET address space in Azure
Below is my code
locals {
  subnets = {
    "snet-general-prod-cus-5315" = {
      cidrs = [cidrsubnet(data.azurerm_virtual_network.default.address_space[0],3,0)]
      service = { endpoints = [
          "Microsoft.KeyVault",
          "Microsoft.Storage",
          "Microsoft.Web",
          "Microsoft.EventHub",
          "Microsoft.Sql",
          "Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB"
          ],
          delegations = {}
      }
    }
    "snet-webapp-prod-cus-6401" = {
      cidrs = [cidrsubnet(data.azurerm_virtual_network.default.address_space[0],3,1)]
      service = { endpoints = [ ],
          delegations = {
            "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms" = {
            actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
            name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
            }
          }
      }
    }
    "snet-sqlmi-prod-cus-5951" = {
      cidrs = [cidrsubnet(data.azurerm_virtual_network.default.address_space[0],3,2)]
      service = { endpoints = [ ],
          delegations = {
            "Microsoft.Sql/managedinstances" = {
            actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
            name    = "Microsoft.Sql/managedinstances"
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "default" {
  name                = local.virtual_network_name
  resource_group_name = local.managed_resource_group_name
}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "default" {
  for_each             = local.subnets 
  name                 = local.subnets[each.key]
  address_prefixes     = local.subnets[each.key].cidrs  
  resource_group_name  = local.managed_resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.default.name
}



│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is "snet-sqlmi-prod-cus-5951"
│     │ local.subnets is object with 3 attributes
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "name": string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on resources.vnet.tf line 60, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "default":
│   60:   name                 = local.subnets[each.key]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is "snet-general-prod-cus-5315"
│     │ local.subnets is object with 3 attributes
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "name": string required.


My assumption based on the information provided in the question would have to be that you want the key in the map to be the value for the name parameter. In that case you should use each.key and each.value accordingly:
resource "azurerm_subnet" "default" {
  for_each             = local.subnets 
  name                 = each.key
  address_prefixes     = each.value.cidrs  
  resource_group_name  = local.managed_resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.default.name
}

The documentation contains more information. Note also that the error message provides debug information.
